# Merging cells in Excel using Mata xl()

Tags: stata

I have a number of Excel tables created using the Stata commands `putexcel` or `export excel`.

I need to format many of the tables after saving.  Because of the size of the files, I am trying to use `mata` for the formatting, rather than `putexcel`.

This works well, except when I try to merge two cells into one:

```
*Build sample matrix
set obs 10
foreach i of numlist 1/10{
    gen var`i' = _n + `i'
}

mkmat var1-var10, matrix(m)

*To Excel
quietly putexcel set "Test_Merge.xlsx", sheet("Sheet1") modify
quietly putexcel A1=matrix(m) 

*Prep for mata
mata: b = xl()
mata: b.load_book("Test_Merge.xlsx")

*Left-align some cells
mata: cols = (1,2)
mata: b.set_horizontal_align(1, cols, "left")

*Center some cells
mata: cols = (4,5)
mata: b.set_horizontal_align(1, cols, "center")

*Merge some cells
mata: cols = (7,8)
mata: b.set_horizontal_align(1, cols, "merge")
```

With the `putexcel` command i would do the following:

```
quietly putexcel (G1:H1), merge
```

However, in the `mata` version, the "merge" option appears to simply center the specified cells, rather than merging them together.

Am I misunderstanding the "merge" option in `b.set_horizontal_align()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `mata` function [`b.set.sheet.merge()`](https://www.stata.com/manuals/m-5xl.pdf#m-5xl%28%29Remarksandexamplesset_sheet_merge) instead:

```
clear

*Build sample matrix
set obs 10
foreach i of numlist 1/10{
    gen var`i' = _n + `i'
}

mkmat var1-var10, matrix(m)

*To Excel
quietly putexcel set "Test_Merge.xlsx", sheet("Sheet1") modify
quietly putexcel A1=matrix(m) 

*Prep for mata
mata: b = xl()
mata: b.load_book("Test_Merge.xlsx")

*Left-align some cells
mata: cols = (1,2)
mata: b.set_horizontal_align(1, cols, "left")

*Center some cells
mata: cols = (4,5)
mata: b.set_horizontal_align(1, cols, "center")

*Merge some cells
mata: rows = (1,1)
mata: cols = (7,8)
mata: b.set_sheet_merge("Sheet1", rows, cols)
```

Note the changes in bold, which apply the function to the two cells.